# CSS load animation on UIWebView

Tags: javascript, objective-c, css, ios, uiwebview

I have a very simple `CSS` opacity animation that animates some text in a `UIWebView` when the web view loads. It works great when the body of the HTML is small and quick to render, but for larger bodies, you'll find that the animation runs immediately when the content loads, but the `UIWebView` is not painted on to the view for another second or so, which means the user misses the animation completely.

So my question is, rather than have the fade animation occur on load, I want it to occur when the web view is actually drawn on to my view, and I don't think there are any Objective-C delegate methods that are called when the web view is drawn, so I'm not sure if this can be done on the Objective-C side.

Is there anyway I can call some Javascript (this way I can add the animation manually) immediately when the the web view is actually drawn on my device, rather than when `webViewDidload`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there anyway I can call some Javascript (this way I can add the
>   animation manually) immediately when the the web view is actually
>   drawn on my device, rather than when webViewDidload

maybe you can inject your javascript after your `uiwebview` and your html content is loaded? `webViewDidFinishLoad` this delegate gets called when `uiwebview` and your html dom tree created.

Comment: Yes but there is about a 1-2 second difference between the time didFinishLoad is called and the time the content is actually drawn on the screen.

Comment: hmm, then i dont think there is anyway. maybe you can introduce a x seconds delay in your javascript code. but this is a hack and dirty way to solve your problem.

Comment: why dont you try this. keep your `UIWebView` loaded. just set it to hidden. That way the loadtime for uiwebview is drastically cut down. This might lead to your app consuming a little bit more memory though, but still this could work.

Comment: which one? keeping your UIWebView loaded?

Answer (score 0):

does uiwebview didfinishload fire for you when page loads?  if so, you could use that function in objectiveC to execute  js command to start your CSS animation

Comment: That fires when the content loads, but has nothing to do with when the content is actually drawn on to the screen.

Comment: gotcha, if you add a javasript section at the end of your html page to fire a command, does that command fire after your content is drawn?  If so, there are some options.  Another option is to fire the animation after X seconds, but kind of hacky